# Text matching technique on top of large dataset to get text matching IDs

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, lucene, fuzzy-search

I have a very large dataset like in below format . I want to apply some text matching technique (against user provided input) which will yield matching percentage/score and based on that (above some threshold) I want to get the IDs.

I tried to store my data in `Elasticsearch` and perform `more like this query`.
But for given keywords e.g. `Fan spinning` , Its pulling lot of unwanted records , where there might be single irrelevant `Fan` word present in large text.

Looking for some best suitable approach to address the mentioned problem

[image]

Comment: I think this question is probably too subjective (one person's "very expensive" is another person's "reasonably priced") - and can only be answered with opinions. Such questions are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) here. Give FuzzyWuzzy and Lucene a try - see what you think. (With Lucene, for example, the "expense" will largely be up-front, to build the index; after that, searches may well be surprisingly fast.)

Comment: What is your dataset size? and what makes you think that would be expensive operations to run some basic fuzzy queries ? .

Comment: There is not enough background to properly answer the question.

Comment: @thturk I have almost 120000 Records and also the Text is actually Large text ( It has Defect title + description combined)

Comment: @amirouche actually i am looking for some suggestion on approach . i tried to load the data in pandas Dataframe and tried to apply `FuzzyWuzzy`  matching but its taking around 7-8 mins to scan the entire DF and yield matching result.

Comment: Pandas implies that the language of choice is Python. If so, you may want to tag your question with that. At least that will get more eyeballs on the question - but I think it remains [too broad and opinion-based](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for this site, and may get closed.

Comment: @curiousguy If I understand correctly you want to link words or group of words from texts into a database? is that correct?

Comment: The thing you want to find are a "single-word-without-space or "multiple words with space" ?

Comment: If that is the case lucene / ES is overkill. Answer to my question, I will make a proper response :)

Comment: I am running fuzzy queries and wildcard queries in Lucene bases on 50M Record with combined and formated fields i dont think that your data will even cost taht must . there can be some problem with your code to run and  index files.

Comment: @amirouche I am trying to find "multiple words with space". I have tried to upload my data to ES and do More like this query . Its yielding output but lot of unwanted records are coming. I have updated my question also.

Comment: @curiousguy please improve further the question. What is the text column in the screeshot? what if multiple texts are matches?

Comment: @amirouche I have added one real example with expected result vs current result . Please let me know if that clarifies .

Comment: You need to make it clear what you are trying to achieve "more like this" is certainly not a keyword search. I vote to close. Re-ask the question, it is more clear what you want to achieve. What are the inputs? What is the expected output?...